# How does 1 request every 5 seconds exceed the 30 requests per second limit?

Tags: support, api, rate-limit

I'm doing a run every 5 seconds for this API call:

```
url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/no-answers?pagesize=30&fromdate={date_today}&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow&access_token=" + accessToken + "&key=" + key
```

And sometimes I get this response:

```
{
  "error_id": 502,
  "error_message": "Violation of backoff parameter",
  "error_name": "throttle_violation"
}
```

How is it possible that I am exceeding the limit when it is 30 requests per second?

I don't know about this error answer and from what I've seen in other questions, it's about threshold crossing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: 30 requests/s is the **hard** limit. You will nearly always be limited *way* before that by one of the multiple rate limiting mechanisms. You *definitely* shouldn't take that wording as "it's OK to blast up to 30 requests/s. Oh, and, yes, you can get such responses out of nowhere without having first actually gotten a `backoff`. In addition, the rate limits are (mostly) *per IP address*, so you need to also consider any SE API requests which might be being made by other things (e.g. other browser tabs, other userscripts, other browsers, other people, etc.)

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243773/stack-exchange-api-too-many-requests-from-this-ip-address/243798#243798